# UWP TextBox Text binding not working

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am having some problems with a TextBox.Text binding in UWP. I have been doing WPF for years and typically know what I'm doing in XAML but can't get this binding to work...

I have a TextBox and a Button in the same scope in the XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Margin="10,0,0,0"
            Command="{Binding SearchBusCommand}">Go</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And the bound properties are in the same scope in the ViewModel

```
public ICommand SearchBusCommand { get; }

public string SearchText { get; set; }
```

But, when I type text in the TextBox and hit the Button, the command executes and the SearchText value is null...

My expectation is that when I type text into the TextBox the SearchText property is updated with the Text value.

If I set the value of the SearchText property from the ViewModel it does appear in the TextBox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok it seems that in UWP the binding on the TextBox.Text property is OneWay by default..!

I had to set the binding to TwoWay to make it work.

```
<TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

WHY WOULD THEY DO THAT!?

Comment: @AlexDrenea but why would you want to OneWay bind on TextBox.Text? That's what a TextBlock is for?

Comment: @GlenThomas Binding uses default mode OneWay everywhere, it doesn't depend on control/property where it's used.. It may be confusing if it'll be varied

Comment: I have a Xamarin professional certificate and started using UWP without tutorial. This is why am i here. Thanks for your answer.