# UWP Two-way binding in a control template

Tags: wpf, uwp, binding, win-universal-app, custom-controls

I'm having a custom control with a Text property which should be two-way bind to a property of the data context.
The binding happens only at the beginning (one-time I guess) but doesn't respond to any text change.

my custom control:

```
public sealed class MyTextControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public MyTextControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyTextControl);
    }
}
```

the control template:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyTextControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyTextControl">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <TextBox
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

i'm calling to the control:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <myTextControl:MyTextControl
        Width="500"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="{x:Bind Greeting, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <Button
        Margin="50"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Submit" />
</StackPanel>
```

Greeting is a DP in the code behind set to Hello World!

I expect to reach a break point in Greeting or Text on text changed but I'm not.
Seems like the Two-way binding not working well.
Anything different from WPF ? How can I make it work ?

Comment: naa it's not the problem.
because also on LostFocus (the default) it's not working.
just for the practice I've added this to the TextBox in the template but still doesn't hit the break point.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39907515/1136211

Comment: no it's not duplicate.
the binding two way binding must be specified not only on the control itself but also inside the control template.
the question you specified is a simple scenario for binding with no custom control at all

Comment: Still the problem is the same. No TwoWay Binding by default.

Comment: same problem can come up in varies ways.
this is not a scenario of binding inside a control but inside a control template.
argue with that fact is poor

Comment: If the case was Two-Way binding on Greeting I would not argue on that

Answer (score 3):

## Quick Answer

First, [a `{TemplateBinding}` is always a one-way binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension#remarks).

Second, starting with Windows 10, version 1809, [you can use the `{x:Bind}` markup extension anywhere you use `{TemplateBinding}` in a `ControlTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension#xbind-in-controltemplate).

Therefore, **you can use `{x:Bind}` inside a `ControlTemplate` instead of `{TemplateBinding}` and have two-way binding functionality** (`mode=TwoWay`).

### Extra help

Having said that, using `{x:Bind}` inside a `ControlTemplate` isn't as trivial as replacing the instances of `{TemplateBinding}` with `{x:Bind}`. It involves some other changes. Having into account that Visual Studio automatically (1) creates a class file named `MyControl.cs` and (2) allocates the control's style with the `ControlTemplate` within `SomeProject\Themes\Generic.xaml` (if the folder and the resources file don't exist already, they are created), **follow these instructions to have your control working with {x:Bind}**:

1. Remember that the [`TargetType` property is required (not optional) on `ControlTemplate` when using `{x:Bind}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension#xbind-in-controltemplate).
2. In the folder `Themes\`, create a new class file named `Generic.xaml.cs` and declare a public sealed partial class named `Generic` with a public constructor that just calls `InitializeComponent`:

   ```
   // Themes\Generic.xaml.cs
   namespace SomeSolution.SomeProject.Themes
   {
       public sealed partial class Generic
       {
           public Generic() => InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```

   *(See note A.)*
3. Add the following as an attribute to the root tag of `Generic.xaml`:

   ```
   <!-- Themes\Generic.xaml -->
   <ResourceDictionary x:Class="SomeProject.Themes.Generic" ...>
       ...
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

   *(See note B.)*
4. Instantiate the ready-for-xBind type (`Generic`) containing the control's style in `Application.Resources`(`.MergedDictionaries`) :

   ```
   <!-- App.xaml -->
   <Application ...>
       <Application.Resource>
           <Generic xmlns="using:Whatever.Namespace" />
       </Application.Resources>
       ...
   </Application>
   ```

   *(See notes C, D and E.)*

---

#### Notes

A. [`{x:Bind}` markup extension generates source code at compile-time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#resource-dictionaries-with-xbind), so it needs to initialize the generated code].

B. [`x:Class` joins partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-class-attribute) between markup and code-behind].

C. [A resource dictionary with code-behind is reused by instantiating its type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-class-attribute) (so that `InitializeComponent` is called) instead of referencing its filename.

D. [`Application.Resources` can be reused everywhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#look-up-resources-in-code). If this isn't intended, the class with the style can be instantiated in `SomePage.Resources`, [`SomeFrameworkElement.Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.resources?view=winrt-18362), etc.

E. Resources in `Themes\Generic.xaml` don't need to be "merged" with `Application.Resources` in order for them to be available everywhere. They are available by convention. However, since this resource dictionary *does* need to be instantiated explicitly, **there's no need to name the files `Generic.xaml` and `Generic.xaml.cs` (within `Themes/`)**. The files (and the class) can be named differently and the namespace and location can differ as well. **As long as they're instantiated accordingly, the control will work**.

Comment: Hey there. When declaring inside Application.Resources like this   <Generic xmlns="using:Whatever.Namespace" /> I get an error that states it doesn't find the Generic type inside the namespace. What namespace exactly am I supposed to use for it to detect the type correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Small changes from WPF which take some time to understand
I needed also to update the template to support two-way binding

```
Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

There were time we had FrameworkPropertyMetaData but no more...